# Function calling function yields "can't be found"

Tags: powershell

In a powershell script I have the following scructure:

```
function Process-File {
    Param ( $FileObject )
    ...
}
function Process-Directory {
    Param ( $DirObject )
    ...
    Get-Childitem $DirObject | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        Process-File -FileObject $_
    }
}
Get-Childitem -Path $Location -directory | ForEach-Object {
    Process-Directory -DirObject $_
}
```

This yields the error:

```
The term 'Process-File' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
```

What is going on? Why does Process-Directory can be found but Process-File doesn't?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, but.. inside function ProcessFile I don't see what the automatic variable `$_` does in there. Also, you should name functions according to the `Verb-Noun` convention.

Comment: I realized that the issue was calling the function from a ForEach-Object with the parallel flag. I think I'll delete the question in the next 12 hours since it was the wrong question in the first place and there are already other questions covering the correct situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that -parallel is actually starting up new jobs. And those would know nothing about the function that you've only defined locally.

Either you have to send the scriptblock with the foreach call as you do with plain -jobs (don't know if that works with foreach) or define the function again in the foreach script block or globally as in a script profile or a powershell module.

The solution below is the "easiest" to write, but also actually defines the "inner" function over and over again.

```
function Process-Directory {
    Param ( $DirObject )
    ...

    Get-Childitem $DirObject | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
        function Process-File {
            Param ( $FileObject )
            ...
        }# end inner function

        Process-File -FileObject $_
    }
}
Get-Childitem -Path $Location -directory | ForEach-Object {
    Process-Directory -DirObject $_
}
```